# Write bash script which takes input from pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I am always typing things like this:

```
cat some_list_of_elements.txt | awk '{print "\047"$1"\047"}' | paste -d, -s
```

It takes a list of items from a file, wraps each in quotes, and merges them together in a comma-separated list.

Rather than typing out all that stuff, I'd like to do something like this:

```
cat some_list_of_elements.txt | csl
```

How can `csl` be implemented in bash? Is there a way to do it as an alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
alias csl='awk '\''{print "\047"$1"\047"}'\'' | paste -d, -s'
```

Thanks to @roadmr for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

```
alias csl="awk '{print "\047"$1"\047"}' | paste -d, -s"
```

then just `cat whatever | csl`

This seems to work, but really doesn't, for the reasons mentioned in the comments below. See them for actual, good working solutions :)

By the way, this is not ubuntu-specific, so feel free to post on stackoverflow.com if my answer doesn't work for you.

Comment: Not working for me. The awk command outputs "20007" for each line.

Comment: This works.... `alias csl='awk '\''{print "\047"$1"\047"}'\'' | paste -d, -s'`

Comment: @frankadelic, you could also use a function: `csl() { awk '{print "\047" $1 "\047"}' - | paste -d, -s; }` -- don't have to mess around with a lot of quotes and backslashes. I explicitly put the argument `-` for awk to denote that it's reading from stdin.

Comment: @roadmr, the difficulty is you're using double quotes as the "outer" quotes, so the `$1` is getting substituted at the time  you're *defining* the alias.